# App is not indexed in Search results in test apk

Tags: android, google-search, google-crawlers, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I'm facing a strange issue in app Indexing. Our play store APK uses older version of app indexing API and is working fine. App is indexed for google search results. But, after I migrated to fire base and updated App Indexing API, app is not indexed in search results.  I have tried the below testing techniques and all are working.

```
1. Testing a URL
2. Android Debug Bridge
3. Testing App Indexing API behavior
4. Android Studio -> run -> configuration test
5.  HTTP URL testing tool using bar code scanner app
```

I'm getting error for the below 2 tests :

```
1. Google App Indexing Test from Android Studio : 
    Error :
    Network error, please try later.
    1. Google cannot index this page using Google bot crawling.
    2.  Google cannot index this page using the App Indexing API.
```

But network connection was good

```
2. Preview Search Result on Android:
    Error :
   Getting : ERROR:Google can't find your URL in the index. Check for correct formatting and provide at least one HTTP/HTTPS scheme URL.  This is informed to server team. But they negleted it saying, even for other app urls, getting same error.
```

in both case url format was : `"android-app/package-name/scheme/host/path"`  . We have used custom scheme here.

I also tried Fetch as Google test using the test APK :

Tested the APK in 2 scenarios:

```
1. Test APK,  landing page(without uri), throws internal error
2. Test APK, app URI, no error -> showed deep linked story preview in the app
```

As per the documentation internal error means : 
`android:minSdkVersion must be at least 17 (in my AndroidManifest.xml is 15)` or that my app is unable to run on x86 hardware (which I have no idea) and same tests works in play store build, without any error.

```
Note : Auto Complete search is working
```

Most of the tests are working fine. But none of them are showing in search results for me. But same story is indexed properly in playstore build. is it because , i have installed test APK ?

Also, `In google App ->Phone Search -> my app is not listed.` In devices in which our app is listed, search results are shown only in those devices, when they are on test APK.  But it doesn't work in devices in which app is not listed in Phone search. As per documentation, it lists by default, when a app is opened .But not happening in my phone. Is there a way to enable them manually ?

Comment: I've the same issue, it may be the service is down?

Comment: same issue here with 10 version. with old gcm version everything was working ok